# eglCreateImageKHR is working only with RGBA8888 format. How to send RGB888 data?

Tags: opengl-es, gpu, egl, mali-400

I implemented an opengl-es application running on mali-400 gpu. I grab the 1280x960 RGB buffer from camera and render on GPU , I use zero copy operation using `EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import` extension.

my problem is that the Besler camera gives frames in RGB888 format.
but `eglCreateImageKHR` is working only if I give RGBA8888 format . If I pass RGB888 to `eglCreateImageKHR` it gives black screen and also egl image returned is 0.

will I have to convert RGB888 to RGBA8888 before passing? what are the other options. below is my code.

```
EGLint egl_img_attr[] = { EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR, EGL_TRUE,
    EGL_DMA_BUF_PLANE0_FD_EXT, buffer->dbuf_fd,
    EGL_DMA_BUF_PLANE0_OFFSET_EXT, 0,
    EGL_DMA_BUF_PLANE0_PITCH_EXT, TEX_WIDTH * 3,
    EGL_WIDTH, TEX_WIDTH,
    EGL_HEIGHT, TEX_HEIGHT,
    EGL_LINUX_DRM_FOURCC_EXT, DRM_FORMAT_RGBA8888 ,
    EGL_NONE, EGL_NONE };

buffer->egl_img = eglCreateImageKHR(egl_dpy, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, EGL_LINUX_DMA_BUF_EXT, (EGLClientBuffer)0, egl_img_attr);
```

Comment: I converted RGB to RGBA8888 and it is working. But the question is why eglCreateImageKHR doen't work with RGB888?

Comment: Just to avoid duplicating effort, I answered your question here: https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/graphics/f/discussions/13632/rgb888-format-not-working-in-eglcreateimagekhr